# Multiplying with positive and negative noise modifier

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I have a baked f-curve, and I also have a script to unbake it. I want to multiply this f-curve with positive and negative noise, however, the noise modifier only uses positive and negative if I use replace, If I use multiply it ranges from 0 to 1...
And i can't use replace since I want it to scale proportionally.

Workarounds are also an option, maybe some channel or driver-thingy?

Here an image of what I mean, I basically want to multiply the blue curve with the red curve
[image: Blender]

Comment: A negative strength will "invert" the curve. The problem would be the small values in between like 0.001 effectively flatten the curve. Increasing the depth will help the noise stick to the old curve shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem! I added the original curve and the noise on seperate Action strips for the same property into the NLA Editor and set the Blending on the Noise to Multiply

[image]