# NLA Influence not working

Tags: animation, modifiers, nla-editor

I want to add some Noise to an Action by animating the influence of the Action Track. So I enabled "Animated Influence" and inserted Noise into the Influence, but the Influence doesn't change at all, it just stays at 0.

[image: NLA Editor]

[image: Graph Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround! I added the original curve and some noise onto seperate Action strips for the same property into the NLA Editor and then set the Blending on the Noise to Multiply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add some noise to the strip add a noise modifier. A strip modifier works like an [f-curve modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html) but it applies the effect to all channels in the one instance of the strip.

[image: nla strip modifier]

Blender v2.78 moved the modifiers panel to a tab, earlier versions have modifiers located under the other properties.

Comment: nah, I did not express that properly. What I'm trying here is actually a workaround for my other question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78633/multiplying-with-positive-and-negative-noise-modifier  but now that I'm thinking over it, that won't work too since there is no such thing as negative influence...

Comment: I found my answer. I'll post it here later.